# Trying to sent a post request in Python to download csv file from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, python-requests

I am trying to download a .csv (there is an "Export Csv </>" button) file from a website, through a Python script. What I want to do is to emulate the Network post request that I can see from Network tab in Dev tools when I manually download the CSV. When I just try to sent the post request from a simple Python script, a Response [500] is returned. How could i solve? Thank you very much for your help and support

My code:

```
requests.post('https://provepip.ipex.it/PipWa/Front/GetCsv', 'ExportData.csv')
```

Response:

```
<Response [500]>
```

Comment: Sending a POST request to https://provepip.ipex.it/PipWa/Front/GetCsv does not return anything on my side.

Comment: Have a closer look at your web inspector.  The browser sends a payload---the data in JSON, and then the server renders as csv.  (you'd expect this with POST anyhow, as just getting a resource should be GET, but there are some odd servers out there)

Comment: when I sent this request through Python requests I get the response 500

Comment: @nms_coding yep, and did you try printing its .text?  500 = server error. The server sends an html page telling you the request was malformatted.

Comment: there's also a session cookie in the request, which is likely needed to get the response.  You likely aren't going to have much luck trying to scrape like this: you either need to get the cookie, work out the payload, etc to get the data, or else you need to use something like selenium to control a real browser to do it for you

Comment: Yes I think that using Selenium could be a less painful solution. Thank You @2e0byo

Answer (score 0):

Having had a look at the site, there seem to be two HTTP calls involved in the download.  The first call returns the name of a CSV file, and then the second calls allows you to download that CSV file. Try the following:

```
import session
with requests.session() as session:
    # First page of results
    payload = {
        "Page": 1,
        "Rows": 25,
        "SortDirections": ["desc", "desc"],
        "SortFields": ["ThreadId", "Id"],
    }
    # Make call to create CSV file
    req = session.post(
        url="https://provepip.ipex.it/PipWa/Front/CreateCsv", data=payload
    )

    # Remove surrounding quotes from the result
    filename = req.content.decode("utf-8")
    stripped_filename = filename.replace('"', "")

    req = session.post(
        url="https://provepip.ipex.it/PipWa/Front/GetCsv",
        data={"Filename": stripped_filename},
    )
    print(req.content.decode("utf-8"))    # returns CSV data
```